# Why Luhn's algorithm?

Tags: database, cs50, luhn

Hey I just wanted to know why do we use the algorithm to begin with when we can just check the number with the data base and conclude if it exists as a valid card or not? I am new to programming and I am taking cs50, luhan's algorithm came on the first problem set, so I don't know any further than the basics on data bases, but what I am questioning seems very logical to me.

Thanks.

Comment: there is no database which contains all valid credit cards

Comment: okay, but if the database of the provider doesnt have the card number, does it matter if its valid or not, it wont go through.

Comment: i.e. if the card is valid it doesnt axiomatically mean it is an actual current card. proving its valid is of no need right? 
Sorry if it seems like i am arguing about something stupid, but i really dont see the point :(

Comment: when new user wants to pay for some service - it will provide credit card number which is not in providers' database yet

Comment: Oh, I see, so until they 'send' the request to the database, instead of bothering it by always checking, they apply Luhn's law as a basic checkpoint. Thanks.